# Backbone router: Assemble complete url from route and parameters

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm using the 'before' function in Backbone's router to intercept route changes so I can check client side authentication:

```
routes() {
        return {
            'search/:query/:page': 'search',
        };
}

before(route, args) {
     if (!userModel.get("Authenticated")) {
            //I'll do authentication logic here
            return false;
     } 
}
```

After any authentication is done, I want to navigate to the original requested route.

Say my route is something like /search/somequery/1, the parameters in the before function will be:

```
route   "search/:query/:page" 
args     ["somequery", "1"]
```

Is there an easy way to assemble the complete requested url so I can call

```
this.navigate(returnUrl)
```

after my authentication is done?

Comment: Whoops, I can just use Backbone.history.fragment